# Particles.js doesn't interact with the cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

I have a particles.js file as background of my website, it shows correctly but does not interact with the mouse, it is only set acting as if it were a video.

Thank you so much in advance.

UPDATE: Is solved in comments below. Just change 'window' instead of 'canvas' on interaction in your app.js

Answer (score 3):

Solved. First code is that I haved, and second code is the solution. I'll post this in case it's helpful to anyone.

```js
"interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "bubble"
      },
```

```js
"interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "window",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "bubble"
      },
```

Comment: I tried this "answer" and it did not change a thing with my interactivity